# Is it possible to use "look down on" in a phrase without meaning disdain?

Tags: phrasal-verbs, ambiguity, semantics

Is it possible to use "look down on" in a phrase, without meaning disdain?

Example: (if I'm standing on the moon) Can I use "look down on Earth", to describe a physical act of viewing something from a higher vantage point without implying any sense of disdain? Or people will misunderstand I'm despising the Earth?

Comment: "[I climbed the hill, I wanted to look down on you](https://genius.com/Belle-and-sebastian-if-she-wants-me-lyrics)"

Comment: My house on the hill looks down on a pretty valley. Nothing disdainful about that.

Comment: Thank you so much!✨️

Comment: In certain contexts - from a hillside overlooking the town, say, you might feasibly talk about *looking **out** on the town below* rather than *looking **down** on it*. But in practice, native speakers would normally understand the literal rather than metaphoric phrasal verb sense without giving it any thought. Such potential ambiguity is more relevant to non-native speakers, who inevitably have to *think* more about the words, and thus may end up thinking the wrong thing.

Comment: See copyleaks for the answer: it says AI content detected. Not a real person.

Comment: " see copyleaks" (it's a free online programme). Ironically these programmes which are supposed to detect plagiarism and whether a text is generated by a human or not, are themselves  *not human* i.e. AI-powered. They are not infallible, and shouldn't be relied on. In any case, a good answer, was rightly deleted by a mod because the author did not reference its very source (ChatGPT). I think the most telling aspect was the high number of answers they posted. If you see any user who posts six or seven answers in one day nowadays that will be considered suspicious activity.

Comment: Thank you so much @FumbleFingers for you answer and time! I appreciate it✨️

Comment: I didn't think about AI answering here. Thank you for reminding us that this is possible!